# Socket.io-client not connecting to server when path server option is specified

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I have an `express 4` server I'm trying to integrate with `Socket.IO`.

If I do `io.attach(serverInstance)` on server and `io.connect("http://localhost:3002")` on a react client using `socket.io-client` connection is established and the server logs something like `socket connection active, id: 3IjhKYkpY19D6nWHAAAB, client ip: ::ffff:127.0.0.1`.

But when I pass `{path: "/socket/socket.io"}` as `io.attach(serverInstance, {path: "/socket/socket.io"})` and `io.connect("http://localhost:3002", {path: "/socket/socket.io"})` nothing is logged, i.e., connection is not being made. I recently started learning `socket.io` so i don't know much.

I want that incoming socket connection should be requested at `localhost:3002/socket` and not `localhost:3002/`.

**server side:**

```
class SocketInterface {
  constructor() {
    this.server = undefined; // will hold the server instance once defined.
    this.io = socket(); // referencing socket interface.

    this.getServerReference = this.getServerReference.bind(this);
    this.ioDotOn = this.ioDotOn.bind(this);
   }

  /**
   * this method defines the sever reference once the server starts.
   * @param {http.Server} server: reference to the http server.
   */
  getServerReference(server) {
    this.server = server;
    this.io.attach(server, {path: "/socket/socket.io"});
  }

  /**
   * this method executes io.on()
   */
  ioDotOn() {
    if (this.server) {
      this.io.on("connection", socket => {
        // when connection is established
        const ip =
          socket.handshake.headers["x-forwarded-for"] ||
          socket.conn.remoteAddress;

        console.log(
          `socket connection active, id: ${socket.id}, client ip: ${ip}`
        );

        // when connection breaks
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
          console.log("user gone");
        });
      });
    } else throw new Error("Server is undefined");
  }
}
```

I require this class in `server.js` as

```
const socketInterface = require("./socket/socket-io");
let server = undefined;

// first connect to local db.
MongoInterface.mongoConnect(err => {
  if (err) {
    // if error, occurs terminate.
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    // if connected to MongoDB, get a reference to the taskDbOps singleton object.
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB server");

    // start the server and store a reference to the server.
    server = app.listen(config.PORT, err => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log("Application Server Running on Port: ", config.PORT);
    });

    // starting the socket interface.
    if (server) {
      socketInterface.getServerReference(server);
      socketInterface.ioDotOn(); // socket service.
    }
  }
});
```

**react client**
It is a mock client that has an `api.js` for socket connection like so:
`api.js`

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

function x() {
  const socketConn = io.connect("http://localhost:3002", {
    path: "/socket/socket.io"
  });
}
export { x };
```

this is imported in `app.js` like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { x } from "./api";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {

  x(); //connecting to socket

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm using `socket.io 2.3`

**Thanks**

Comment: could you please provide relevant code examples from your client and server application?  Have you registered event listeners for the messages that you're attempting to emit and capture?

Comment: Why do you need to set a custom path?  Socket.io has a default path that "just works" if you don't mess with it.  FYI, path should start with a leading `/`.  And, please show us the actual client and server code in proper context.  Socket.io is NOT requested at `localhost:3002/` by default.  It has its own default path already of `/socket.io`.  You don't need to mess with this at all.

Comment: @CrankyCoder I have added the relevant client and server code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried adding a leading '/', it is still not connecting. I'm just trying things with socket.io as i explore its documentation and work on a project. I posted question because I cannot understand why it won't work. I saw some similar questions here but they all say what is in the docs. But it is not working for me.

Comment: Your server code is crazy complicated looking for just starting a socket.io server.  I cannot follow what it's doing.  For example, you do this `this.io = socket();`.  What is that?  Then, you later do `this.io.attach(server, {path: "/socket/socket.io"});`, but what is `server` in that code?

Comment: Then, in the client, you call `x();`, but inside of `x()`, you don't store `socketConn` in any place that it could be used by anyone.  Sorry, but none of this makes any sense.  It looks about 5x more complicated than it needs to be.  I'd suggest you go make yourself a nice little test server and test client that follows the socket.io tutorial.  When that works just fine and only when that works just fine, you can then break parts of that out into your own structure one piece at a time keeping it working as you go.

Comment: Starting from day one with a complicated looking structure makes it a lot harder to see where you went wrong.  I don't think I can help you by code inspection with no ability to debug anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is a whole project, what I posted is a single module from it that not complete too. I tried this on new minimal server and it works, thanks for the suggestion, now I have figure out what is wrong in this code.

Comment: @jfriend00, I got it working, `server` you were asking for is defined at top in `server.js` (check edit). I moved that declaration inside the `else` as `let server = app.listen()`. And it works with `path`. Any insights on this?

Comment: I don't know what it was like before so kind of hard for me to see what exactly you changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const socketInterface = require("./socket/socket-io");

// first connect to local db.
MongoInterface.mongoConnect(err => {
  if (err) {
    // if error, occurs terminate.
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    // if connected to MongoDB, get a reference to the taskDbOps singleton object.
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB server");

    // start the server and store a reference to the server.
    // binding the server variable here resolves the problem
    let server = app.listen(config.PORT, err => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log("Application Server Running on Port: ", config.PORT);
    });

    // starting the socket interface.
    if (server) {
      socketInterface.getServerReference(server);
      socketInterface.ioDotOn(); // socket service.
    }
  }
});
```